# PHP: how to handle curl response

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to make script which checks if site is up or down. Everything works fine, but when site is NOT a site, I mean that site does not exist. And then php execution load time increase. I want somehow to handle this. How to check if site doesn't exists and break curl session? Here is my script:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://86.100.69.228/'); // e.g. for this will increase execution time because the site doesn't exists
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $status_code;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define timeout by setting CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT options of cURL transfer  in `curl_setopt`. If site is down cURL will stop working and you'll catch it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a site is down `CURL` might not be the best option since you are not check a full URL such as `http://eample.com/abx.phpx` ... when you are using services such as "Secured DNS" such as Comodo  http://www.comodo.com/secure-dns/ all website would return `200` because request are automatically forwarded for verification so you would always load site with IP address `92.242.144.10`  [Search 92.242.144.10](https://www.google.com.ng/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=13&gs_id=2&xhr=t&q=92.242.144.10&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=92.242.144.10&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=ca9f3912ec7596e5&biw=944&bih=1071)

My advice is just simply ping the server

```
function ping($host)
{
    exec(sprintf('ping -n 2 %s', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
    return $rval === 0;
}

$result = ping("86.100.69.228");
```

Out check the socket directly

```
function pingSocket($host, $port = 80, $timeout = 3) {
    $fsock = fsockopen ( $host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout );
    if (! $fsock) {
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

$result = pingSocket ( "86.100.69.228" );
```

This works better most times